# how to calculate the udp checksum when the udp payload is and odd number e.g 45 bytes payload

Tags: networking, udp, transport-protocol, checksum

I am new to networking and was learning about the UDP Protocol and i came through the term UDP checksum. I searched the internet spent so much time finding the correct way to calculate the UDP checksum but no one is teaching the exact way to calculate the UDP checksum.
I am stuck at this point. Kindly teach me how to calculate the UDP checksum.
I shall be thankful to you for this favour.

Comment: *" I searched the internet spent so much time finding the correct way to calculate the UDP checksum but no one is teaching the exact way to calculate the UDP checksum."* - I think you either need to improve your skills of searching or lower your expectations of what you get. I recommend you start with the obvious [wikipedia: UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) which describes the algorithm used in detail and also links to documents like RFC 1071 with pseudo  code. And just searching for [udp checksum code](https://www.google.com/search?q=udp+checksum+code) is also useful

Comment: We don't teach here, we answer on-topic questions as detailed in the [help/on-topic]. And it's really all in [RFC 768](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc768.html)...